# Leaflet setview() to look at County Map

Tags: r, leaflet

Hello all experts out there,

I am very new to R and leaflet

I would like to create a shiny dashboard and within it, I want to create a map with leaflet. Here is how I want it to be, first, the user will pick a state, then, you may or may not pick a county. So if they pick a state I would like to use setview() to just look at the chosen state, and if they pick a state and a county, then setview() to look at the chosen county.

So first I want to make sure my leaflet code works first, before I embed it into shiny server. So I ran the following code assuming that the user picks California state and county Los Angeles.

I got the following error and not sure how to fix it.

Any suggestion? Thank you so much in advance!

```
Error in cut.default(x, binsToUse, labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE,  : 
  'breaks' are not unique

> head(lonlat)
  STATE            COUNTY         county.State       lon      lat
1    AK   KENAI PENINSULA   KENAI PENINSULA,AK -151.3044 60.58293
2    AK         ANCHORAGE         ANCHORAGE,AK -149.8557 61.22002
3    AK            DENALI            DENALI,AK -145.8662 63.04024
4    AK            BETHEL            BETHEL,AK -161.7558 60.79222
5    AK MATANUSKA-SUSITNA MATANUSKA-SUSITNA,AK -150.5125 61.54361
6    AK     KODIAK ISLAND     KODIAK ISLAND,AK -152.3539 57.80459
> 



states <- readOGR("cb_2015_us_state_20m.shp",
                  layer = "cb_2015_us_state_20m", GDAL1_integer64_policy = TRUE)

states <- subset(states, states$STUSPS %in% c("CA"))
class(states)

leaflet(data = map_dat[map_dat$STATE %in% "CA" &
                         map_dat$COUNTY %in% "LOS ANGELES",]) %>%
  addProviderTiles(
    providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
    options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)

  ) %>%
  addPolygons(data=states,color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
              fillColor = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", ALAND)(ALAND),
              highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
                                                  bringToFront = TRUE)) 

selectedCounty <- lonlat[lonlat$COUNTY == "LOS ANGELES" &&
                           lonlat$STATE == "CA", ]
#leafletProxy(mapId = "allmap") %>%
setView(lng = selectedCounty$lon, lat = selectedCounty$lat, zoom = 5)
```